# Using variadic templates to implement Get(Tuple) got "parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’" error

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I want to implement something like std::get(std::tuple), having a tuple class:

```
template<typename ... Types> class Tuple;
template<> class Tuple<> {};
template<typename First, typename ... Rest>
class Tuple<First, Rest...>: private Tuple<Rest...> {
  First Member;
 public:
  Tuple(const First& first, const Rest& ... rest):
      Tuple<Rest...>(rest...), Member(first) {}

  const First& Head() const {
    return Member;
  }

  const Tuple<Rest...>& Tail() const {
    return *this;
  }
};
```

I've also implemented a helper struct tuple_element.

```
template<size_t I, class T>
struct tuple_element;

template<size_t I, class Head, class ... Tail>
struct tuple_element<I, Tuple<Head, Tail...> >:
    tuple_element<I - 1, Tuple<Tail...> > {};

template<class Head, class ... Tail>
struct tuple_element<0, Tuple<Head, Tail...> > {
  typedef Head type;
};
```

But I can't realise how to implement Get(Tuple) function. I think I've tried everything.
My last try:

```
template<class T, class Head, class ... Tail>
T Get(size_t pos, const Tuple<Head, Tail...>& t) {
  if (pos > 0) {
    return Get<T>(pos - 1, t.Tail());
  }
  return t.Head();
}
template<size_t Pos, class Head, class ... Tail>
typename tuple_element<Pos, Tuple<Head, Tail...> >::type
    Get(const Tuple<Head, Tail...>& t) {
  return Get<typename tuple_element<Pos, Tuple<Head, Tail...> >::type>(Pos, t);
}
```

But I got an error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Get<T>(pos - 1, t.Tail());` - `Tail` is a type here, that won't work.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!
I'm happy right now!

Comment: You need to use either `enable_if` or template specializations. The first `Get` function returns either `T` or `Head` depending on a runtime condition - that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it. I've implemented it using template specialization, but due to disability of function partial specialization I've modified tuple_element struct above. That's what I finally have:

```
template<size_t I, class T>
struct TupleElement;

template<size_t I, class Head, class ... Rest>
struct TupleElement<I, Tuple<Head, Rest...> >:
    public TupleElement<I - 1, Tuple<Rest...> > {
  static typename TupleElement<I, Tuple<Head, Rest...> >::Type
      Get(const Tuple<Head, Rest...>& t) {
    return TupleElement<I - 1, Tuple<Rest...> >::Get(t.Tail());
  }
};

template<class Head, class ... Rest>
struct TupleElement<0, Tuple<Head, Rest...> > {
  typedef Head Type;
  static typename TupleElement<0, Tuple<Head, Rest...> >::Type
      Get(const Tuple<Head, Rest...>& t) {
    return t.Head();
  }
};

template<size_t Pos, class Head, class ... Rest>
typename TupleElement<Pos, Tuple<Head, Rest...> >::Type
    Get(const Tuple<Head, Rest...>& t) {
  return TupleElement<Pos, Tuple<Head, Rest...> >::Get(t);
}
```

Thank you all for useful advice.